# What is the story of the woman who lifted a mountain?

Tags: vaishnavism, sri-vaishnava

Parashara Bhattar was a famous Sri Vaishnava Acharya who became the head of the Sri Vaishnava sect after Ramanujacharya departed the Earth.  He was the son of Ramanujacharya’s shishya Kurathalwan, and he’s the Sri Vaishnava commentator on the Vishnu Sahasranamam.  In any case, Parashara Bhattar once imparted to his chief disciple Nanjiyar ten words of advice for Prapannas, those who have performed Sharanagati or complete surrender to Vishnu.  [Here](http://acharya.org/ar/tenwords/bhattar10.html) is his sixth word of advice:

> Do not focus on the ordinary Shastras and instead focus on the special Shastra which is Bhagavad Vishayam. Even in matters of performing rituals, do the same. One has to be steady in this and not have any doubts. There is no need to question this as "This is possible only for a few such as Bharata and Thirukkannamangai Andan.” Even a wild horse can be tamed over time. For those who have a young and steady heart, this is not difficult. **Is it not said that a woman started by lifting a small stone, then a rock and so on, till she lifted a whole mountain?**

Bhagavad Vishayam refers to the poems of the Alwars and the commentaries on them.  But I’m interested in the part in bold.  My question is, what is the story of the woman who lifted a mountain by first lifting smaller rocks?

Is it mentioned in any scriptures, or is it just a folktale? Do any Sri Vaishnavas works shed light on this?

Comment: Why the downvotes?

Comment: Because Nobody can answer that. It's just a folktale. Read the line "Is it not said...?" BTW I didn't downvote.

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto It could mean said in some scripture.  In any case, Sri Vaishnava works may clarify whether it's a folktale or a scriptural story or what.

Comment: In any case this question might survive, but won't get any answer as I think there is no real story behind that.

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto It sounds like an interesting story - a woman lifting an entire mountain.  It sounds like a supernatural occurence that may be mentioned in some scripture.  I assume this is no ordinary woman.

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto Downvotes because it's unanswerable and a folktale? Since when are we doing that? In puranas, in commentaries to BG, other important scriptures, there are countless sentences like "it is said". Does that make any difference if it is a folklore?

Comment: @Sarva Did I say that ?

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto Yeah, I can see that. "Because no body can answer that.. it's just a folktale". Using just implies that it is less important compared to something other and "Because No body can answer that" implies that it's a valid reason for DV when you really DV. So avoid such words. Moreover, there's no proof that it's a folktale. Many folktales are present in puranas.